# Commit the working directory to different branch and switch back

Tags: shell, git, sh

The aim of this script is to snapshot the current working directory of a git repository to another branch. Afterwards, it switches back to the original branch and restores the original state, including the working directory and staged changes.

```
#!/bin/sh

function git_snapshot() {
  # Usage: SNAPSHOT=$(git_snapshot <backup_branch> "<commit message>")
  set -e

  # Save the current state.
  BEFORE=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
  if [[ "$BEFORE" == 'HEAD' ]]; then
    BEFORE=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
  fi
  (>&2 echo "Starting at $BEFORE.")
  git stash push --include-untracked
  (>&2 echo "Stashed changes ($(git rev-parse stash@{0})).")

  # Commit files to other branch.
  git checkout "$1"
  git read-tree -um $BEFORE
  git commit -m "$2"
  (>&2 echo "Saved last commit ($(git rev-parse HEAD)).")
  git stash apply --index stash@{0}
  git add -A
  git commit --amend --no-edit
  (>&2 echo "Amended uncommitted changes ($(git rev-parse HEAD)).")
  SNAPSHOT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

  # Switch back and restore state.
  git checkout $BEFORE
  git stash apply --index stash@{0}
  (>&2 echo "Restored changes.")

  echo $SNAPSHOT
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting it [through shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) results in quite a lot of cleanups.

Apart from the issues raised there, I'd suggest that at the end of your script, you might want to `git stash pop` instead of `git stash apply` when restoring your state.

Inside the function body, you may use `local` to declare the `BEFORE` variable. While `local` is not POSIX compliant, all of [GNU and BSD compliant shells](//stackoverflow.com/a/18600920/1190388) support the `local` keyword.